# how i get mails from gmail over imap with python

Tags: python, imap, gmail-imap

This is my script, the auth_string is right, i tryed this smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587') and its worked, imap is activ in my gmail settings, and yes, please help me :)

```
def command_to_url(command):
    return '%s/%s' % (GOOGLE_ACCOUNTS_BASE_URL, command)

def call_refresh_token(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token):
    params = {}
    params['client_id'] = client_id
    params['client_secret'] = client_secret
    params['refresh_token'] = refresh_token
    params['grant_type'] = 'refresh_token'
    request_url = command_to_url('o/oauth2/token')
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode('UTF-8')).read().decode('UTF-8')
    return json.loads(response)

def refresh_authorization(google_client_id, google_client_secret, refresh_token):
    response = call_refresh_token(google_client_id, google_client_secret, refresh_token)
    return response['access_token'], response['expires_in']

def generate_oauth2_string(username, access_token, as_base64=False):
    auth_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (username, access_token)
    if as_base64:
        auth_string = base64.b64encode(auth_string.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
    return auth_string

def test_imap(user, auth_string):
    imap_conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', port=993)
    imap_conn.debug = 4
    imap_conn.authenticate('XOAUTH2 ', lambda x: auth_string)

access_token, expires_in = refresh_authorization(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN)
auth_string = generate_oauth2_string('---------@gmail.com', access_token, as_base64=True)

test_imap('---------@gmail.com', auth_string)

response:
  30:07.30 > b'KOHE1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 '
  30:07.32 < b'+ '
  30:07.32 write literal size 376
  30:07.41 < b'+ eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ=='
  30:07.41 write literal size 376
  30:07.48 < b'KOHE1 BAD Invalid SASL argument. q16mb213626858wmq'
  30:07.48 BAD response: b'Invalid SASL argument. q16mb213626858wmq'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\path_to_script\mail_send.py", line 148, in <module>
    test_imap('---------@gmail.com', auth_string)
  File "E:\path_to_script\mail_send.py", line 78, in test_imap
    imap_conn.authenticate('XOAUTH2 ', lambda x: auth_string)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 428, in authenticate
    typ, dat = self._simple_command('AUTHENTICATE', mech)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 1196, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 1027, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: AUTHENTICATE command error: BAD [b'Invalid SASL argument. q16mb213626858wmq']
```

I try this since 3 days and i dont anymore :[]

Comment: Does your OAUTH token have the correct scope to access IMAP?  Are you formatting it correctly with the user and bearer token as described in Googles OAUTH extensions for IMAO document? (I’m on a mobile device and can’t de-Base64 at the moment)

Comment: @Max decoded its 
{"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
and yes its correctly formated

Comment: Yes, I see that is the result.  What did you write?  I understand the contents are temporarily sensitive, but you don't show how you build auth_string, etc. which is quite relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that my auth_string was as_base64 encoded, but imap wants the 'not encoded' auth_string

access_token, expires_in = refresh_authorization(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN)
auth_string = generate_oauth2_string('---------@gmail.com', access_token, as_base64=False)

test_imap('---------@gmail.com', auth_string)

Comment: Hi @Justin Schmitt can you maybe provided a fully working example please? 
Thank you

Comment: @Wathfea did u solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try step by step:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
try:
    rv, data = M.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    print "Login failed."
    sys.exit(1)
```

This will test IMAP4_SSL with Gmail against your credentials (without OAUTH2, so verify this configuration to be enabled).

If that works, and XOAUTH2 does not, well clearly I must question your statement that the auth string is correct.

For example, the error you get back seems to refer to a scope of `mail.google.com`, while I would have expected `imap.google.com`. Is this correct?

Also, is the extra space after 'XOAUTH2' a typo, or is it in the original code? That might mess with the algo selection mechanism.

You might want to re-start afresh from the [Google Python XOAUTH2 sample code](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough) and build up from there.

Comment: since May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password

so i must use XOAUTH2, 
my "auth_string" works, because i can send mails over smtp with the xoauth2 credentials 

if i use mail.google.com i get the error :"socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed"

the extra space in 'XOAUTH2' was a typo :)

i tryed to log in over openssl and the auth works, (A01 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 dxxx=)
the only error i get was a "tag BAD Could not parse command" by every command

Comment: i copied the AUTHENTICATE from this example